# Enums in Switch Statements cannot be resolved

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

Perhaps someone could fill my understanding gap:
I have an enum that looks like this:

```
enum MyEnum {

    VALUE_1("id1", "name"),
    VALUE_2("id2", "name")

    ...
}
```

When I do this in my code, it works fine:

```
if(MyEnum.VALUE_1.getId().equals(someVar)) {

}
```

But this, doesn't compile

```
switch (someVar) {

    case MyEnum.VALUE_1.getId():
    ...
}
```

IDE complains that `MyEnum` cannot be resolved.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to use the result of a method call in a case expression, which is illegal in Java, because case labels require constant expressions, which can be resolved at compile time.  The result of a method call is not a constant expression, so it cannot be used as a case label.

You must use your `if` statement; it doesn't need a constant expression.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I never knew that. +1

Answer (score 0):

You must use constants in case labels, thus method invocations are not permitted. Nevertheless, to be able to use the switch statement and to make the code a bit more readable, you could implement something like this:

```
enum MyEnum {

    VALUE_1("id1", "name"),
    VALUE_2("id2", "name"),
    ...

    private static final Map<String, MyEnum> instances = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        for (MyEnum myEnum : values()) {
            instances.put(myEnum.getId(), myEnum);
        }
    }

    public static MyEnum getById(String id) {
        return instances.get(id);
    }
}
```

Then you can use the utility `getById` method whenever you need to get the corresponding enum instance for the provided id, for example in a switch statement:

```
switch (MyEnum.getById(someVar)) {
    case VALUE_1:
    ...
}
```